# Selecting neighbours in an iteration using Select by Location

Tags: pyqgis, iteration

In the 'Select by location' tool, there is an option for Selected features only. When it's ticked, the resulting code for selecting touching polygons of a selected feature looks something like this:

```
processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {
            'INPUT': boundary_layer,
            'PREDICATE':[4],
            'INTERSECT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition('gadm36_AFG_2_3040aec4_9c3d_472d_aad3_311351d800e8', True),
            'METHOD':0})
```

I need to use this code in a loop, where at the bottom of each loop, more features are selected. I don't know how to address this in the `'INTERSECT'`, where currently a static address is given to `QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition`. One can use the following, which is not suitable for iteration.

```
'INTERSECT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(boundary_layer.id(), True),
```

In the documentation, it is mentioned:

> Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource

```
    Accepted data types:
            - str: layer ID
            - str: layer name
            - str: layer source
            - QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition
            - QgsProperty
            - QgsVectorLayer
```

But I don't know which one is suitable for this purpose.

**Context**: In a loop, I am starting with one polygon, find its neighbours using 'Select by location', touching, selected features only. Then I choose one of the neighbours based on some criteria and append its ID to a `list`, which already includes the starting polygon's ID. At the end of the loop, I choose both features using             `layer.selectByIds(list)`. Going back to the beginning of the loop, now the neighbours of these two features have to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me in the `while` loop. I am leaving some extra code before it, so it makes a bit more sense. Feel free to add/suggest edits.

**Context**: The idea is to draw a boundary for a city to match a certain population. The code receives the UN population of the city (feat) as an input, and one by one, adds the neighbouring polygons and their population to the selection, until it reaches the UN population. The final selection can be saved as the city's boundary.

```
for feat in features:
    feat_population = int(feat['population']) # UN population

    # Select first feature
    processing.run("qgis:selectbyattribute", {\
    'INPUT': ,\
    'FIELD':'fid',\
    'OPERATOR':0,\
    'VALUE': feat.id(),\
    'METHOD':0,\
    'PROGRESS':None})

    boundary_list = [feat.id()]

    # Access the population field of the first feature
    for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
        total_boundaries_pop = feat['population']

    iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
    activeLayer = iface.activeLayer()

    while total_boundaries_pop < feat_population:

        # Find the neighbours of a feature (or some features)
        processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {
        'INPUT': layer,
        'PREDICATE':[4],
        'INTERSECT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(activeLayer.id(), True),
        'METHOD':0,
        'PROGRESS':None})

        layer.deselect(boundary_list)

        # Find the neighbouring polygon with the higest population
        population = 0
        for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
            if feat['pop_countsum'] > population:
                selected_boundary_id = feat.id()
                population = feat['pop_countsum']

        boundary_list.append(selected_boundary_id)
        total_boundaries_pop += population

        layer.selectByIds(boundary_list)
```